# MySQL Query Taking forever to execute

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to pull a simple report. I have prepared a query but its taking forever to execute.

PFB Query:-

```
select sc.product_name as product_name,
       (select count(id) from hg_scratch_card
           where product_name=sc.product_name
             and (review_received_date between '2019-12-01'
                                           and '2019-12-21') ) as RR_COUNT,
       (select count(id) from hg_scratch_card
           where product_name=sc.product_name
             and (review_updated_date between '2019-12-01'
                                          and '2019-12-21') ) as RU_COUNT
from hg_scratch_card sc
where sc.product_name !=''
order by RR_COUNT desc
limit 3
```

Please suggest how can i optimize the query. I have index on all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 1 row for each `product_name` then you should `group by product_name` and use conditional aggregation:

```
select product_name,
  sum(review_received_date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-21') as RR_COUNT,
  sum(review_updated_date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-21') as RU_COUNT
from hg_scratch_card
where product_name !=''
group by product_name
order by RR_COUNT desc
limit 3
```

Comment: Thank you so mcuh @forpas. It works,. I was trying with the same query but didn't know i can use sum in date ranges.

Comment: Actually sum() is not summing the dates but 1s(TRUE) and 0s(FALSE). And don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the OP's original query:

```
INDEX(product_name, review_received_date)
INDEX(product_name, review_updated_date)
```

For forpas's query:

```
INDEX(product_name, review_received_date, review_updated_date)
```

(And only because it is "covering")

Guessing from the names, I would expect `review_received_date` to always be before `review_updated_date`.  In that case, either formulation would benefit from

```
AND review_received_date >= '2019-12-01'
```

in the *outer* `WHERE`.